# How to turn off or close debugging mode in VS-Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I turned on debugging mode in my VS Code and now want to turn it off, but can't work out how.

I have this floating menu:
[image]

And my bottom toolbar is still orange:[image]

How do I revert to my old set up? (I've seen on other posts that people want to hide the floating menu, but I think I want to just switch debugging back off if possible?)

Comment: press the orange/red square button

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and nothing happens. The button animates but eveything just remains there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the solution I expected or wanted, but I disabled the debugger via my extension panel:
[image]

And then disabled the extension and had to reload VS Code for the change to take effect:

[image]

I has done the trick but seems like a faffy way of achieving switching it back off again.

Answer (score 6):

For turn of debug on vs code .
On the floating menu click on end(Red color rectangular block).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

"Disable Source Mapped Stepping" might be what you are trying to achieve. Less resources are used, when disabled.

[image: Disable Source Mapped Stepping]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to red blank box, but it's not worked.
I deleted the launch.json. My environment is Mac + c++ development

Answer (score 0):

I removed the .vscode folder including launch.json and extensions.json. It works. The debugger was disabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).